# How to get the data of plugin-config in store-front of shopware6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I succssefully get data in store-front from entity by the following code.

```
    public function addCustomfield(FooterPageletLoadedEvent $event): void
    {
        $customfieldResponse = $this->customfieldRoute->load(new Criteria(), $event->getSalesChannelContext());

        $event->getPagelet()->addExtension('custom_field', $customfieldResponse->getcustomfield());
    }
```

according to above code my custom data add in footer pagelet by api call successfully.

I wnat to get data of my plugin-config data in footer pagelet.

If you have any suggestion then tell me!

Answer (score 2):

You can access the plugin config directly over twig inside the template:

```
{% set myConfig = config('MyPluginName.config.myConfigValue') %}
```

Comment: A bundle of thanks #j_elfering.
After a log of time, I found the solution with the help of @j_elfering